# The seven scientists: Difficulties with maximum likelihood

Tags: self-study, normal-distribution, maximum-likelihood, inference, information-theory

I'm working on the [exercise 22.15 - the seven scientists](http://www.inference.org.uk/mackay/itprnn/ps/300.318.pdf) - in the book by David Mackay where he claimed that Maximum Likelihood method might have difficulties with. However, when I applied the maximum likelihood, it seems to be ok. Maybe my solution is wrong, but I don't know which parts are wrong. Please help me!

The problem is:

> N datapoints $\{x_n\}$ are drawn from N distributions, all of which are Gaussian with a common mean $\mu$  but with different unkonwn standard deviations $\sigma_n$. What are the maximum likelihood parameters $\mu, \{\sigma_n\}$ given the data? For example, seven scientists (A, B, C, D, E, F, G) with wildly-differing experimental skills measure $\mu$. You expect some of them to do accurate work (i.e., to have small $\sigma_n$). What is $\mu$ and how reliable is each scientist?

And here is the measurement of each scientist:

```
+-----------+---------+
| Scientist |   x_n   |
+-----------+---------+
| A         | -27.020 |
| B         |   3.570 |
| C         |   8.191 |
| D         |   9.898 |
| E         |   9.603 |
| F         |   9.945 |
| G         |  10.056 |
+-----------+---------+
```

Here is my answer:

The log-likelihood given the data is: $$
L = ln P(\{x_n\}|\mu, \{\sigma_n\}) = -\sum_n ln(\sigma_n \sqrt{2\pi}) - \sum_n \frac{(x_n - \mu)^2}{2\sigma_n^2}
$$

Take partial derivatives of the likelihood with respect to $\mu$ and $ln\sigma_n$, we get:

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial \mu}L = \sum_n \frac{x_n - \mu}{\sigma_n^2} \\
\frac{\partial}{\partial ln\sigma_n}L = -1 + \frac{(x_n - \mu)^2}{\sigma_n^2}
$$

Setting those partial derivatives to 0 and solve for $\mu$ and $\sigma_n$, we get:
$$
\sigma_n^2 = (x_n - \mu)^2 \\
\sum_n \frac{1}{x_n - \mu} = 0
$$

Applying the data to the equation and solve for $\mu$ using [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28-27.02-x%29%5E-1+%2B+%283.57-x%29%5E-1+%2B+%288.191-x%29%5E-1+%2B+%289.898-x%29%5E-1+%2B+%289.603-x%29%5E-1+%2B+%289.945-x%29%5E-1%2B%2810.056-x%29%5E-1+%3D+0), it gives the following answers:

$$
\mu = -21.9678 \\
\mu = 4.57064 \\
\mu = 8.54439 \\
\mu = 9.69517 \\
\mu = 9.92054 \\
\mu = 10.0168
$$

I wrote a small [Colab notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1W0NO-aUNJH0y3I3MCorkc1swmsUH7h0x?usp=sharing) to check which $\mu$ gives the largest likelihood. It seems the most probable answer is $\mu = 9.92$ which seems Maximum Likelihood still works in this case.

Comment: Please check your differentiation: you seem to have assumed the derivative of $1/\sigma_n^2$ with respect to $\sigma_n$ is $-2/\sigma_n^2.$

Comment: @whuber I take the derivative of $1/\sigma_n^2$ with respect to $ln \sigma_n$, not $\sigma_n$. Btw, I take the derivative of $L$ with respect to $\sigma_n$, the result is similar: $\frac{\partial}{\partial \sigma_n}L = -1/\sigma_n + (x_n - \mu)^2/\sigma_n^3 = 1/\sigma_n[-1 + (x_n - \mu)^2/\sigma_n^2]$

Comment: Thank you for explaining your notation.  Be careful with using Wolfram Alpha, because it doesn't necessarily return all solutions or even any valid solutions. I find it instructive to contemplate a simpler version of this problem, say with $N=1.$